# Why are there two application data directories?

Tags: windows-xp

Why are there two application data directories?

C:\Documents and Settings\bob\Application Data

C:\Documents and Settings\bob\Local Settings\Application Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that occurs when you have a roaming profile. The files in the Local Settings folder will not be copied to the server. Although I always thought that the local settings folder was stored inside the Application Data folder.

Comment: I guess since i'm not on a domain, it makes no difference.. but why does OE, while it stores the address book in the roaming one .  It stores the emails, *.dbx, in the local one?

Comment: I'm not really an expert on Outlook Express. But perhaps they didn't design it for roaming profiles. Since Microsoft makes an expensive Outlook that's designed for that purpose.